# How far can you throw a halfling?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Character STR 14

Weight of halfling and halfling's gear: 50 lbs.

Halfling is willing and able.

How far could one throw a halfling?

Would the answer change if the halfling was not willing and resisted bring by thrown?

Comment: I'm asking because I may make a halfling with average DEX and am thinking of how he will get across gaps and chasms with the reduced land speed penalty to jumping.

Comment: Related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72904/how-to-throw-another-player-character

Comment: Some readers may find relevant [these guidelines](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/91581/8610) for *D&D 3.5*.

Answer (score 4):

The Rules As Written are not very helpful here.  You *could* technically use the rules for thrown improvised weapons:

> To determine the size category and appropriate damage for an improvised weapon, compare its relative size and damage potential to the weapon list to find a reasonable match.
>
> Halve [the weight] for Small weapons and double it for Large weapons.

(a greataxe weighs 12lb, so a Huge greataxe weighs 48lb)

> Throwing a light or one-handed weapon is a standard action, while throwing a two-handed weapon is a full-round action.

The range increment on an improvised thrown weapon is 10ft, and you can throw for at most five range increments.

Putting all these rules together, we learn that a Huge creature can throw a 50lb halfling 50ft by treating him as an improvised weapon, and a Large creature can't throw a 50lb halfling at all.

The creature's strength does not matter [when using these rules].

---

If your ally happens to be a Giant with the "rock throwing" special ability, your situation improves dramatically.  A Large size giant can throw a Small size rock up to 600 feet (120ft range increment * 5 range increments); if he can throw a Small rock, he can throw a Small halfling as well.

If your ally is not a Giant with the "rock throwing" special ability, this does not help you.

---

If the halfling is not willing, the thrower would need to make a grapple check to pick up the halfling, and at least another grapple check to throw him. Some DMs might rule that you can't throw an unwilling creature at all (though you could still "move" one, per the grapple rules).

---

A real world example: an [Olympic athlete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athletics_at_the_1920_Summer_Olympics_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_56_pound_weight_throw) can throw a 56-pound weight up to 11 meters (35ish feet).

---

In practice, all adventuring parties contain people who can't jump -- most commonly clerics with their heavy plate armor, but wizards generally aren't athletic either.  When an adventuring party needs to cross a chasm, they have two choices.  Most commonly they throw a grappling hook across and use the rope to make the trip; if there's absolutely nothing for the grappling hook to get a purchase on, they just have their strongest character jump across and then *hold* the rope for everyone else.

Comment: I would like to point out that it isnt as simple as "hold the rope and cross", the rope gives a bonus, a character helping gives another (or multiple characters), but ultimately, whoever is crossing the chasm has to make a roll (or take 10), and hope it's enough to cross.

Comment: This is why the entrance pit at sunless citatel caused to many TPKs before the adventure even started.

Comment: Climbing a knotted rope is DC 5, and you can take 10. No base armor gives an armor check penalty worse than -7. I think it's pretty safe.